# Non-equivalence of $\mathbb R$ in different set theories

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, foundations

I believe I miss something simple as I'm not quite good in foundations. Please tell me if I use some notion incorrectly.

As you know $\mathbb R$ is defined uniquely up to isomorphism. The theory of $\mathbb R$ is given by the second-order arithmetic, which is categorical and denoted by $Z_2$. The reals also can be defined in set theory. But taking into account the axiom of determinacy (AD) in fact we have two incompatible set theories: ZFC and ZF+AD. The question of existence of non-measurable sets is answered differently in these theories. And so the theories of reals in two set theories are not equivalent.
Does it mean $Z_2$ is incompatible with one of them? If yes, then with which of them, and does it compatible with the other? Does it mean the unique (standard) model of $Z_2$ is also model in only one set theory?

Comment: No, rather it means that the surrounding set theory determines the content of $Z_2$.

Comment: Well, this is under assumption that the uniqueness of $\mathbb{R}$ also preserves things like the existence of a non-measurable sets. Does it?
 Analogously $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are equinumerous (isomorphic in Set) but when you introduce additional structure (e.g. semigroup structure) then they suddenly become non-isomorphic.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Ahh, so that's the point. The definition of $Z_2$ assumes we have set theory, and so we have different $Z_2$'s for different set theories, right?

Comment: Yes, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

The categoricity of $\mathbb R$ is always in reference to a fixed model of set theory.  You can have the same set theory but different models thereof.
In this sense I disagree with the conclusion of the exchange of *comments* following the *question* and agree with Andrés's adjective "essentially" which however is rather significant when spelled out.  For example, there are models of ZF+ACC that feature nonmeasurable sets and other models that don't.

Remark by Andrés: "The issue manifests itself much earlier.  For instance, (conceivably) there are models of ZF where Con(ZF) holds and models where it fails, and this is a Π$_1^0$ statement, much simpler complexity-wise than a question about measurable sets, which actually is not even within the scope of $Z_2$ (unless the nonmeasurability manifests itself fairly early)."

Comment: The issue manifests itself much earlier. For instance, (conceivably) there are models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ where $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZF})$ holds and models where it fails, and this is a $\Pi^0_1$ statement, much simpler complexity-wise than a question about measurable sets, which actually is not even within the scope of $Z_2$ (unless the nonmeasurability manifests itself fairly early).

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, that's a very good point. While the kind of issue I mentioned may be more familiar to a traditionally trained mathematician, the point you make deserves being elaborated more fully. What I was mainly pointing out that one needs to be careful about the model/theory distinction. Would you like to post your *comment* as a separate *answer*? Otherwise with your permission  I could add your *comment* at the end of my *answer* since the point deserves to be made more prominently.

Comment: Go ahead. ${ }$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've investigated the subject a little and didn't get why do we need a fixed set theory model for the categoricity. [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248965/do-set-theorists-use-informal-set-theory-as-their-meta-theory-when-talking-about/249006#249006) helped me to see how the theories and the results of my question are related to each other. Namely, we have $Z_2$, set theory and model theory formulated in that set theory, and that model theory tells us $Z_2$ is categorical. So we need a particular set _theory_, not a model. What I've missed?

Comment: True, categoricity refers to a *theory* but your question express puzzlement over "non-equivalent R's". What I was pointing out is that the *uniqueness* of R can only make sense in the context of a fixed model of set theory. People losely speak of "categoricity" as characterizing R uniquely (in fact my using the term "categoricity" at the beginning of my *answer* is a case of such loose usage) but the uniqueness in question is not absolute in any sense but rather relative to a background model of set theory. @Seriy

Comment: P.S. Are you referring to Burak's answer there? It does not seem to mention $Z_2$ specifically.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Yeah, this non-absoluteness of many notions of set theory is really confusing. But I've already realized the question of non-measurable sets is in fact beyond the scope of $Z_2$, as Andrés mentioned, it's simply not expressible in $Z_2$ alone (right?), and so the categoricity doesn't apply to it.

Comment: @MikhailKatz What do you mean saying _uniqueness_? How it differs from categoricity? And what is "a background model of set theory"?

Comment: By *uniqueness* of $\mathbb R$ I mean the fact that, given a model of set theory, $\mathbb R$ is uniquely characterized therein by a short list of properties: archimedean complete ordered field (this list is actually redundant but let's leave aside the details for now). Thus *uniqueness* involves talk about *models*, so it is not the same as categoricity which is a property of *theories*. As you probably know, set *theory* admits lots of *models*; for example, some of them satisfy the continuum hypothesis and others don't.